# How do I make an ExtJS drag and drop tree be copy only -- not remove items from the display?

Tags: javascript, extjs, drag-and-drop

I've created a tree using the treeviewdragdrop plugin like this:

```
Ext.create('Ext.tree.Panel', {
            viewConfig: {
                plugins: {
                    ptype: 'treeviewdragdrop'
                },
                listeners: {
                    drop: function (... do stuff
```

By default if you drag an item from one parent to another it *moves* it and you can ctrl-click to copy, but I just want to copy -- that is, I don't want it to stop displaying in the original node.  I'm not doing anything in the drop to affect the store, so I'm not forcing a remove

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Oh, this was easy.

Add copy: true, like this:

```
Ext.create('Ext.tree.Panel', {
            viewConfig: {
                plugins: {
                    ptype: 'treeviewdragdrop'
                },
                copy: true,
                listeners: {
                    drop: function (... do stuff
```

It does change the data that hits the drop listener, but that can be worked with.